# jsp exception while converting arraylist to jsp array

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts

```
<script>
  var availableTags = [
    <% for (int i = 0; i < ApplicationName.size(); i++) { %>
      <%= ApplicationName.get(i) %>
      <%= i + 1 < ApplicationName.size() ? ",":"" %>
    <% } %>
  ];

  $(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });

  function value()
  {
    alert(document.getElementById('tags').value);
    var a=document.getElementById('tags').value;
    return a;
  }
</script>
```

It gives me below error:

`Struts has detected an unhandled exception:`

Please tell where am I going wrong.

Comment: You should tag your question appropriately, put at least **struts** and **jsp** on it.

Comment: Can you please put the rest of your error? This is inconclusive: `Struts has detected an unhandled exception:`

Comment: Put the code in scriptlet to the action.

Comment: You should look at the rendered output. Also, ew, scriptlets.

Answer (score 1):

You may try putting the following in quotes:

```
<%= "'"+ApplicationName.get(i)+"'" %>
```